# How do I extract the final HTML after the JS manipulation of pages?

Tags: c#, javascript, html

Let me explain with an example.
Imagine I've got a webpage witch contains a `JS` that modifies the `HTML` of the page itself.
I want to put in a `string` the final content of the `HTML` modified by the JS.

How can I do?

Comment: You wouldn't typically do that with C#. By the time JS has gotten around to manipulating your webpage, you are in the *client-side context*. The only way you could access the rendered HTML would be to manipulate it in JS, and then use something like web services or web sockets to communicate the changes back to the server.

Comment: A good solution for me can be to open a browser to render the final HTML and then take it to a .NET application.. but how?

Comment: Once the rendered HTML is ready, use JS to send to it to the server via a web service or web sockets. However, I'm struggling to come up with a scenario where you want to do this. Can you help me understand what value you expect from this?

Comment: It's a Web scraping scenario.. the page uses AngularJS to modify the HTML content in an Ajaxified way. I don't own the website. But it's unreadable (very bad user experience) and I want to extract the information and change the way they are presented.

Comment: You can access the dom via c# opening the page in your application of you are client side. That's the live representation of the page, isn't that enough?

Comment: @Gabber: I think it would solve my problems, but how do I do it? Now my question becomes: "In c# is possible to access the dom of the live representation of the page? How?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accesso the dom via c# opening the page in a webbrowser component. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290341%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a tutorial to start.
If you don't want the component to be shown you can safely hide it.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the render method of the page and capture the html

```
Public override void Render(HtmlTextWriter htmlW)
{
    TextWriter txtW = new StrigWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTxtW = new HtmlTextWriter(txtW);
    base.Render(htmlTxtW);
    string output = txtW.toString();
    htmlW.Write(txtW.toString());
}
```

The output string contains the html source code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Where should I do this? it seems c# code. But c# can render pages? Or I'd better ask which class has the method I have to override?

Comment: @Sam Render is part of page life-cycle events but it is not an event, it is just a method. Refer to this for more info
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX)